# How can I store the results into a text file?

Tags: c++, c, scip

I'm solving a VRP with SCIP and I wish to export the results of the optimization into a text file. I use the following code but fails when calls the SCIPwriteBestSol function.

```
FILE* file;
file = fopen("Solution.sol", "w");
SCIP_CALL(SCIPprintBestSol(scip, file, FALSE));
fclose(file);
```

Comment: `file2 = fopen...`, sure about the `file2`?

Comment: You should check for errors after opening the file. Also how does the code fail?

Comment: try to check the return of fopen. It will return a NULL pointer if it's fails
then just check if (file != nullptr)

Comment: Already edited the error (with the "file2") but the SCIPwriteBestSol function throws me an Access Violation error.

Comment: It does not make sense to call `fflush` immediately after `fopen`.

Comment: If you get an access violation error, then there's something wrong with the arguments to your function call.  Either `scip` isn't set up correctly, or `file` is not set up correctly.  It is unlikely that the `FALSE` argument is the cause of trouble.  If you've checked that `file` is OK between the `fopen()` and the `SCIP_CALL`, then `scip` is presumably not initialized correctly.  You show nothing of what's done with it, so it's impossible for us to guess more about what's up.  Nevertheless, the most likely problem is the file not being opened.

Comment: The function uses the following arguments:
SCIP_RETCODE SCIPprintBestSol  ( SCIP * scip, FILE * file, SCIP_Bool printzeros). The fopen works just fine, I used the suggestion of RomMer.

Answer (score 2):

If the following call works (i.e., prints the solution to console), then your problem comes from the I/O methods. If it fails as well, you have to check your SCIP status, i.e., whether you have a solution at all. If this does not work, I suggest to write to the SCIP mailing list / report a bug.

```
SCIP_CALL(SCIPprintBestSol(scip, stdout, FALSE));
```

Answer (score 0):

check the return value of fopen()

as the [manual](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) says fopen will return a null pointer if the function call fails

then firstly do it

```
if ((file = fopen("Solution.sol", "w")) != nullptr)
{
// do your stuff
}
```

Comment: RomMer I did as you suggested and the condition is met, but the code keeps failing in the SCIPprintBestSol function. I jabr doubts with the FILE* component, the function gives me an Access Violation error.